# Make app more effecient by eliminating extra codes

Tags: java, android

I currently have the following code which starts from **A** all the way to **Z** :

```
if (someId.matches("A") || someId.matches("a")) {
    tvLetCap.setText("A");
    tvLetLow.setText("a");
    ivLetterIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
    btnDisplayWord.setText("A is for APPLE");
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopPlaying();
            mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(MyClass.this, R.raw.a);
            mpSound.setLooping(false);
            mpSound.start();
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnStop.setOnClickListener(stopSound);
            mpSound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}       
if (someId.matches("B") || someId.matches("b")) {
    tvLetCap.setText("B");
    tvLetLow.setText("b");
    ivLetterIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
    btnDisplayWord.setText("B is for BALL");
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(MyClass.this, R.raw.b);
            mpSound.setLooping(false);
                mpSound.start();
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnStop.setOnClickListener(stopSound);
            mpSound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Would this work as oppose to the above:

```
switch(someId) {
    case A:
        setLetter("A");
        addIcon("apple");
        break;
    case B:
        setLetter("B");
        addIcon("ball");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

public void setLetter(String strLetter) {
    tvLetCap.setText(strLetter);
    tvLetLow.setText(strLetter.toLowerCase());
}
public void addIcon(String iconLetter) {
    ivLetterIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable. + iconLetter);
    btnDisplayWord.setText(iconLetter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + " is for " + iconLetter.toUpperCase());
}
```

I am guessing the only issue might be with this line and how would I fix it?:

```
ivLetterIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable. + iconLetter);
```

Also will it be possible to take the entire `btnPlay` function to a different function and just pass the letter like I did with the other functions so it's not repeated over?

Comment: Does the number of lines of code determine how efficient a program is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution: add another parameter to addIcon:

```
public void addIcon(String iconLetter, int iconResource){
    ivLetterIcon.setImageResource(iconResource);
    btnDisplayWord.setText(iconLetter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + " is for " + iconLetter.toUpperCase());
}
```

Then call it with

```
setIcon("apple", R.drawable.apple);
```

As far as reusing the on click listener, it's certainly possible. You could have a single onClick listener that's listening to all the views. When a view is clicked, it's passed in as the argument to the onClick(View view) method. You can use that to find the start/stop button for that view and do whatever to them. Also, there's a useful (and often abused) method pair: setTag(Object object), and getTag(). You might want to look into using those to store the resource ID for the raw audio file you want to play when a button is clicked.

Comment: The second parameter to `MediaPlayer.create` seems to be different for each letter (`R.raw.a`, `R.raw.b` ...) so that might require something extra to be configured for each ID.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what `R` and `R.drawable` are; and what are `R.drawable.apple`, `R.drawable.ball`, etc.?  Assuming those all have the same type, you might want to make R.drawable an *array* where the index is 0 for 'A', 1 for 'B', etc., and initialize it so that R.drawable[0] = (whatever the "apple" is supposed to be), R.drawable[1] = (same for "ball"); then use something like

```
R.drawable[someId.charAt(0).toUpperCase() - 'A']
```

and similarly for `R.raw`.  Then you wouldn't need a `switch` at all.

EDIT by kcoppock:

For example:

```
int[] icons = {
    R.drawable.a,
    R.drawable.b,
    //etc.
};

int[] sounds = {
    R.raw.a,
    R.raw.b,
    //etc.
}
```

and use `icons[index]` and `sounds[index]` to map your values.

Comment: So `R.drawable.apple` which is an image would be same as `R.drawable[someId.charAt(0)]`?

Comment: @SiKni8 My suggestion was that you *make* `R.drawable` an array.  If you do that, you'd be able to use `R.drawable[0]` to get the apple, but you wouldn't be able to use `R.drawable.apple`.  Kcoppock's suggestion is to set up a separate `icons` array which would also work.  The thing is, I have no idea what `R` and `R.drawable` are currently, since you haven't told us.  Thus, I'm forced to guess, and because of that, I don't really know what the exact solution is.  If you give us some code to show what `R` and `R.drawable` are currently, it might help.

Comment: @SiKni8 P.S. If `R` and `R.drawable` are things that the Android library defines--sorry, I wouldn't know about them.  In that case, you might need to follow kcoppock's idea.

Comment: hmmmm... `R.drawable.apple` is the image resource in my `res/drawable/` folder